# Bootstrap's css is not loading

Tags: theming

I am have a website on drupal and have enabled  Bootstrap theme . 
The problem is *http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css* is not loading .
It says "This webpage is not available" when i try to load

*http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css*

in **ubuntu** ,

But when works fine in **windows**.

I have no idea why is this happening .
Plz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your template.php

`function MYTHEME_framework_page_build(&$vars) {
    // Add bootstrap cdn.
    drupal_add_css('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css ', array('type' => 'external'));
}`

where MYTHEME should be replaced with the name of your theme in your MYTHEME.info.

Save the file on your server

clear all chaes and reload the page.

now this should be fixred